# Hypothetical Scenario: How will an Ubuntu computer fare?

Tags: malware, attacks, ubuntu

Imagine, for instance, a wireless network with four to five devices connected. Some are android phones, some are Windows computers. The attacker (Alice), a world-class expert from a nation-state's intelligence agency, gets a head start and has unlimited access to the network and all of the machines for as long as she wants **beforehand**, but must leave the premises and conduct her attack remotely during the scenario. When our scenario begins, Bob is tasked with two goals:

1. Do not allow any passwords or encryption keys to be stolen by Alice.
2. Do not allow Alice to load any malware onto the new machine.

Bob's privacy is not important. All that is important is these two goals. The new machine is a standard installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with full-disk encryption and encrypted home directories for all users. It has been introduced to the network for the first time. Bob is a very savvy user and is resistant to social engineering attacks. If Alice can cause Bob to fail at either goal in 24 hours, she wins. Otherwise, Bob wins. In your opinion, who will emerge victorious?

Comment: In the current form the question is too broad. It does neither say what kind of applications are installed on these machines and what activities are done, i.e. web browsing (which browser?), communication between the machines etc. Just having the machines sitting around doing nothing is not a realistic scenario. If you want to have a realistic answer please describe a realistic scenario. Apart from that: flash in Linux is as bad as flash on other platforms and there were lots of  privilege escalation exploits in the last years so  Ubuntu can probably be broken by world-class experts too.

Comment: You are doomed. When alice has that sort of skill level your can only trash all the hardware and try to start over. Your chance of ever having secrets stored in this network diminished once alice had first access. Also i do not understand bob goal #2. Alice already got access and thus already altered the workings of the machines ("malware").

Comment: OS's are not typically the weak part. It's the services running that are weak.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst obviously its impossible to state definitively without knowing the capabilities of the specific nation state attacker in question, I'd be betting on Alice every time here.

There are a load of ways that a nation state attacker could attack this kind of setup.  The obvious approach with physical access to the network in advance would be to take control of the default gateway router/firewall and ensure that it's possible to intecept all of bob's Internet bound traffic.

Then :-

a) Possess a trusted root CA certificate and use it to MITM all SSL encrypted traffic including browsing.  It seems very likely that high-end nation state attackers have either copies of root CA keys which are trusted in browsers used by Ubuntu, or have an intermediate cert signed by such a CA.

b) Use one of their inevitable stock of 0-days to attack whatever browser bob is using at get access that way.  If you look at the results of things like pwn2own private groups have 0-days in popular browsers, so it's kind of inevitable that nation states have the same or better access. Heck you probably wouldn't even need the root CA as most standard browsing will hit some non-encrypted sites that can be easily MITM'd

Frankly I doubt a standard user with any stock OS would stand any chance against  a nation state who had significant interest in getting access to their data.  The shadow brokers releases showed one likely small part of their capabilities.